# I don't know how to change the way text flows in a texarea field for a form?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, textarea

I made a form, but and when the user enters information into it, the text is entered from left to right for the name field and the email field.  However, when someone enters information into the comments field, the text is entered from right to left.  Is there a piece of code or something I need to change, for information to be entered left to right like the other fields? Below is a link to my form.
Thanks you!

http://hsc.unm.edu/admin/compliance/Feedback%20Form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply `text-align: left;`

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS:

```
.webform textarea {
width: 215px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Remove the `text-align: right;`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the text align of the text area to left:

```
text-align : left;
```

EDIT: or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the source, and for some reason you have

```
text-align: right;
```

as CSS for the input field. Remove that line and it should work the way you wanted.